To convert an SQL query from one SQL dialect to another
I wanted to convert sql query from one sql dialect to other like query written in mysql to casendra, mssql, postgresql etc.
for this i have used apache calcite but getting issue. Here i what i have tried
import org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlNode;
import org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser;
import org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParserConfig;
import org.apache.calcite.sql.dialect.SqlDialect;
import org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl;


public class App 
{


   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example SQL query in source dialect (MySQL)
        String sourceSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 = 'value' limit 10;";

        // Configure source and target dialects
        SqlDialect sourceDialect = SqlDialect.DatabaseProduct.MYSQL.getDialect();
        SqlDialect targetDialect = SqlDialect.DatabaseProduct.POSTGRESQL.getDialect();

        // Configure SQL parser with the source dialect
        SqlParser.Config parserConfig = SqlParser.configBuilder()
                .setParserFactory(SqlParserImpl.FACTORY)
                .setConformance(SqlParser.Config.DEFAULT.getConformance())
                .setQuoting(sourceDialect.quoting())
                .setUnquotedCasing(sourceDialect.getUnquotedCasing())
                .setQuotedCasing(sourceDialect.getQuotedCasing())
                .setIdentifierMaxLength(SqlParser.DEFAULT_IDENTIFIER_MAX_LENGTH)
                .build();

        // Parse the SQL query using the configured parser
        SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create(sourceSqlQuery, parserConfig);
        SqlNode sqlNode = parser.parseQuery();

        // Generate equivalent SQL query in the target dialect
        String targetSqlQuery = sqlNode.toSqlString(targetDialect).getSql();

        // Output the converted SQL query
        System.out.println("Converted SQL query in target dialect:");
        System.out.println(targetSqlQuery);
    }
}

getting issue as
 @/tmp/cp_btv8s778pv9oipb0t7f7r60sa.argfile com.azminds.App 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        SqlDialect cannot be resolved to a type
        SqlDialect cannot be resolved
        SqlDialect cannot be resolved to a type
        SqlDialect cannot be resolved
        The method getConformance() is undefined for the type SqlParser.Config

        at com.azminds.App.main(App.java:74)

How can i fix this. OR is there any other alternatives for this problem?

Hi - what do you expect to happen if your source SQL dialect uses a construct that is not supported in the target dialect? For example, the MERGE statement isn't supported in MySQL

@NickW i want to convert mysql query like 'select * from emp limit 10;' into different different sql dialects form, it should result like
for mssql : select top 10 * from emp;
for oracel : select * from emp fetch next 10 rows only;
for postgresql : select * from emp limit 10; and so on for the other sql dialects
